# I just installed mysql module..and everytime i run this code, it gives me error

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

> I want to use the sql.connector module for my local data base, but every time i run the code
>   it gives an error

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="Aaqib",
    passwd="aaqib925"

)
print(db)
```

> Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaqib/Desktop/CODES/tasks.py", line 1354, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/home/aaqib/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .connection_cext import CMySQLConnection
  File "/home/aaqib/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import errors, version
  File "/home/aaqib/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/errors.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/aaqib/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/utils.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .catch23 import struct_unpack, PY2
  File "/home/aaqib/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/catch23.py", line 31, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3743, in <module>
    _numbers.Number.register(Decimal)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Number'
```

Comment: You tagged this question Python 3.6, but the error message indicates you're using Python 2.7.  I expect that's the source of your problem.  Try executing your code with the correct version.

Comment: Yes. I figured it out, but the same problem is for Python 3.6.

Comment: Are you getting exactly the same error?

Comment: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'Aaqib'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` now I am getting this error.

Comment: Are you running the database on port 3306?  Are you sure that you're using the correct password? If the default account is still on the database, try logging into that.

Comment: How can I logout default root account??

Comment: When i run:
`sudo mysql`
I get:
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`